configure proxy for keycloak with spring boot(client and resource server(oauth2)) with nginx inside docker
I need to configure a proxy for aut/reg in my spring boot app
I use docker-compose for local deployment

docker-compose File
name: tracker-v01

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
      POSTGRES_DB: expensedb
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    networks:
      - app-network


  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.1
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: 
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: 
    volumes:
      - './config/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import'
    ports:
      - '8083:8080'
    command: start-dev --import-realm
    networks:
      - app-network

  webapp:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: webapp/target/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
    ports:
      - '6060:8080'
    networks:
      - app-network

  service:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: service/target/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
    ports:
      - '6062:8080'
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - webapp
      - keycloak
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


this is my nginx.conf
events { }

http {
    upstream web_app {
        server webapp:8080;
    }

    upstream keycloak {
        server keycloak:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name auth.application.com;

        location /realms {
            proxy_pass http://keycloak/realms;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name application.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web_app;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}


my app (webapp) is request a permission -> then redirect to (app.yml) issuer-uri: 172.17.0.1:8083/realms/Myrealm
When app start it can reach a 172.17.0.1:8083/ inside the container, but its redirecting when i try browser(certanly cannot reach 172.17.0.1:8083 for sure)
I decide to use server_name at nginx to solve this problem, but it's not work as i think. Cannot reach application.com or application.com:8080 from any app inside my container
